# Statement expression in .net issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, if-statement, savechanges

I have a context in db that contain 4 property that are belong to output of app,
include goTo1, goTo2, goTo3, goTo4 (as string) and also
weightTo1, weightTo2,weightTo3,weightTo4 (as double).

when send a value to method first i check that which one of goTo are null to put value in goTo and belonged weightTo,

```
var P = db.Values.SingleOrDefault(i => i.CarId == Vals.From_CarId);

if (P.goTo1 == null)
{
     P.goTo1 = Vals.CarNumber;
     P.weightTo1= Vals.weight;
     db.SaveChanges();

}
else if (P.goTo2 == null)
{
   P.goTo2 = Vals.CarNumber;
   P.weightTo2= Vals.weight;
   db.SaveChanges();
}
else if (P.goTo3 == null)
{
   P.goTo3 = Vals.CarNumber;
   P.weightTo3= Vals.weight;
   db.SaveChanges();
}
else if(P.goTo4 == null)
{
   P.goTo4 = Vals.CarNumber;
   P.weightTo4= Vals.weight;
   db.SaveChanges();
}
else{}
P.TotalOutPut = P.weightTo1+ P.weightTo2+ P.weightTo3+ P.weightTo4;
```

it works good always but sometimes(maybe under 1% of requests) it doesn't work properly and put a unit value into goTo2 ,goTo3 ,goTo4 together and effect on total value.

for example in a request with arguments (Vals.weight=1500 , Vals.CarNumber=1234):

if goTo1 !=null

it saved 1500 in DataBase(MSSQL) for P.weightTo2 and P.weightTo3 and P.weightTo4 together

and  saved 1234 for goTo2 , goTo3 , goTo4

i dont know what is wrong in this situation, is it belong to statement or is belong to Api request?

like below in DataBase:

before request:

[image]

after request:

[image]

Comment: I dont this there is any issue with the `if else` conditions, there must be something else that may have caused the issue.

Comment: `"but sometimes(maybe under 1% of requests) it doesn't work properly and put a unit value"` How did you checked that? Is the issue reproducible? In addition, do you have any logs thus you can check on it for further details?

Comment: checked base on values that has been saved on data base , don't have any logs for that, that is reproducible between data, unfortunately!

Comment: If that is reproducible , could you please share how can it be reproduced.